# Neo4j Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, neo4j

I am trying to create a Maven project in Eclipse using Neo4J. My Pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>graphproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myneo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>myneo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0-beta01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

However, I am getting the error shown in the image below:

```
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.11 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.11 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000    pom.xml /myneo  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem


ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /myneo  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem


ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.11 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.11 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000    pom.xml /myneo  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
```

[image]

I have tried re downloading the jars by recreating it and also refreshing the repository.

I see that most of the jars have been downloaded:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the entire logs for your error, the image is cropped. Either copy/paste from your IDE or run `mvn clean package` and copy/paste buid log it will probably show the same issues.

Comment: @PierreB. Thank you for the response. I have updated the question with some of the error messages.

Comment: do you have a proxy or something like that on your network ?